# Linux recursive chmod only on sub-directories

Tags: linux, chmod

I'm on linux, and I have a directory with numerous sub-directories and items inside them. I want to run a recursive chmod on all directories and sub-directories but NONE of the files inside those directories.

```
chmod -R 777 {folder}
```

Is there a flag I can add to the chmod command to make the chmod only apply to sub-directories?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

```
find {folder} -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777
```

Comment: This don't work as expected. It will throw an error like: `chmod: missing operand after '777'` 
BUT: `find {folder} -type d -print0 -exec chmod 777 {} \;` work as expected for me.

Answer (score 3):

`find {folder} -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 777`

Answer (score 2):

Try:

find {folder} -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

Comment: In general, find | xargs <foo> will be more efficient than find -exec <foo> as xargs will batch together calls to <foo>, whereas find -exec will call <foo> once for every result. Obviously though there are some situations in which you want a separate call for each result.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the [man pages](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html): 
[image: http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html]

And also corroborated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17091831/538512

use the following format or a derivative thereof `chmod -R u=rwX,go=rwX {folder}`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

We can also run below command to change permission of all folders recursively.

```
sudo chmod 777 -v $(find $PWD -type d)
```