# Linux: Set permission only to directories

Tags: linux, bash, directory, chmod

I have to change the permissions of the `htdocs` directory in apache to a certain group and with certain read/write/execute.

The directories need to have 775 permissions and the files need to have 664.

If I do a recursive 664 to the `htdocs`, then all files and directories will change to 664.

I don't want to change the directories manually.

Is there any way to change only files or directories?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Use find's `-type` option to limit actions to files and directories. Use the `-o` option to specify alternate actions for different types, so you only have to run `find` once, rather than separately for each type.

```
find htdocs -type f -exec chmod 664 {} + -o -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
```

Comment: Better to use `chmod`s built in support. See [Gordon Davisson's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17091413/538512) answer below

Comment: This method is better because if you have a mess of 'x' on basic files that don't need it, this `find` method above cleans them all up, while the `u=rwX,go=rX` does not clean anything up.

Comment: This worked like a charm and saved hours of work. Thank you!!

Answer (score 74):

`chmod` can actually do this itself; the `X` symbolic permission means "execute, if it makes sense" which generally means on directories but not files. So, you can use:

```
chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX /path/to/htdocs
```

The only potential problem is that if any of the plain files already have execute set, `chmod` assumes it's intentional and keeps it. If this is a potential problem *and* you have the GNU version of `chmod` (i.e. you're on Linux), you can get it to remove any stray execute permissions like this:

```
chmod -R a-x,u=rwX,go=rX /path/to/htdocs
```

Unfortunately, this trick doesn't work with the bsd (/macOS) version of `chmod` (I'm not sure about other versions). This is because the bsd version applies the `X` permission based on "the original (unmodified) mode", i.e. whether it had any execute bits *before* the `a-x` modification was done (see [the `man` page](https://man.openbsd.org/chmod.1)).

Comment: Best Answer by far, if you have enough recursive directories, `xargs` will fail eventually. check the [man pages](http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html) for more info

Comment: To combat the potential problem of existing execute flags remaining, you can use:

    `chmod -R a-rwx,u+rwX,go+rX`

This effectively removes all permissions for user, group and other and then only adds those that you want.

Comment: @AxelWilczek Unfortunately, that trick only works with some versions of `chmod`. But I'll add it my answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 6):

Use `find` to search for directories and apply chmod on them:

```
find -type d | xargs chmod 775
```

Use type `f` for file:

```
find -type f | xargs chmod 775
```

Answer (score 4):

Gordon's answer above is correct, but if you're trying to lock down access to a directory tree, it leaves scripts that are executable to the owner also executable to whoever has been granted the capital X.

Using

```
find <path> -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
```

or

```
find <path> -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
```

is safer.

Answer (score 4):

I use something similar to the solution provided by Gordon:

```
chmod -R ug=rw,o=r,a+X /path/to/folder/
```

It should always set 775 for folders and 664 for files, even if the execute permission was previosly set for some file

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
find htdocs -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
```

Comment: This sets the directory permissions, but not the file permissions.

Answer (score -1):

for dirs or files

```
chmod 755 $(find /path/to/base/dir -type d)
chmod 644 $(find /path/to/base/dir -type f)
```